# $slice serverside doesn't work, what changed?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection called groups with attributes url and array of messages.

```
group
   url: 'myGroup'
   messages: [{author: 'john', message: 'hello'}, {..},..]
```

I would like to get only first 50 messages from first publish function.

I found this, but its from 2013 and I'm wondering if something changed since than. If $slice in fields: no longer works, how can I get only first 50 messages from server?
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/978

My code: `return Groups.find({'url': groupId}, {fields: {'messages': {$slice: 50}}});`  There is no visible error on server. The only clue is from console.log-ing the result:

```
I20150126-11:45:30.154(1)? { _mongo: 
I20150126-11:45:30.158(1)?    { _connectCallbacks: [ [Function] ],
I20150126-11:45:30.158(1)?      _observeMultiplexers: 
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?       { '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"zc4srx6hgoq6iZzG7"},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"profile":1,"username":1,"emails":1}}}': [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"users","selector":{"_id":"zc4srx6hgoq6iZzG7","services.resume.loginTokens.hashedToken":"Paq9jfB5AoQjE+73sddR0qG56jLz2ZL73PtMiKzxt9A="},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"_id":1}}}': [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration","selector":{},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"secret":0}}}': [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?         '{"ordered":false,"collectionName":"groups","selector":{"private":false},"options":{"transform":null,"fields":{"groupName":1,"url":1}}}': [Object] },
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?      _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 4, callbacks: [Object] },
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?      _docFetcher: { _mongoConnection: [Circular], _callbacksForCacheKey: {} },
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?      _oplogHandle: 
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?       { _oplogUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/local',
I20150126-11:45:30.159(1)?         _dbName: 'meteor',
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _oplogLastEntryConnection: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _oplogTailConnection: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _stopped: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _tailHandle: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _readyFuture: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _crossbar: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _lastProcessedTS: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _baseOplogSelector: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _catchingUpFutures: [] },
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?      db: 
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?       { domain: null,
I20150126-11:45:30.160(1)?         _events: {},
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         _maxListeners: 10,
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         databaseName: 'meteor',
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         serverConfig: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         options: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         _applicationClosed: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.161(1)?         slaveOk: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         bufferMaxEntries: -1,
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         native_parser: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         bsonLib: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         bson: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         bson_deserializer: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         bson_serializer: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.162(1)?         _state: 'connected',
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         pkFactory: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         forceServerObjectId: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         safe: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         notReplied: {},
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         isInitializing: true,
I20150126-11:45:30.163(1)?         openCalled: true,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         commands: [],
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         logger: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         tag: 1422269128376,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         eventHandlers: [Object],
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         serializeFunctions: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         raw: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         recordQueryStats: false,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         numberOfRetries: 60,
I20150126-11:45:30.164(1)?         readPreference: [Object] },
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?      _primary: '127.0.0.1:3001' },
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?   _cursorDescription: 
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?    { collectionName: 'groups',
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?      selector: { url: 'rR8r4s62cpoMeuzHD', 'users.id': 'zc4srx6hgoq6iZzG7' },
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?      options: { transform: null, fields: [Object] } },
I20150126-11:45:30.165(1)?   _synchronousCursor: null }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output you have included looks like it is from `console.log( Groups.find(...))`.  It is not an error message.

Comment: @user728291 you are correct. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think you should try `console.log( Groups.find(...).fetch() )` and see what you get back by calling the database.

Comment: It started working now and I have no idea, because the code is identical, thanks anyway.